# Exception when I try to combine Autofac with AutoMapper`s IMappingEngine

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, automapper, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

Thats my DI and Automapper setup:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/productdetails")]
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IProductRepository _repository;
    private readonly IMappingEngine _mappingEngine;

    public ProductController(IProductRepository repository, IMappingEngine mappingEngine)
    {
        _repository = repository;
        _mappingEngine = mappingEngine;
    }
}

public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

        //WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);          
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);          
    }
}


public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

        // Filter
        config.Filters.Add(new ActionExceptionFilter());
        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new GlobalExceptionHandler());


        // DI
        // Register services
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<ProductRepository>().As<IProductRepository>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<MappingEngine>().As<IMappingEngine>();

        // AutoMapper
        RegisterAutoMapper(builder);

        // FluentValidation

        // do that finally!
        // This is need that AutoFac works with controller type injection
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        var container = builder.Build();
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
    }

    private static void RegisterAutoMapper(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        var profiles =
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                .SelectMany(GetLoadableTypes)
                .Where(t => t != typeof (Profile) && typeof (Profile).IsAssignableFrom(t));
        foreach (var profile in profiles)
        {
            Mapper.Configuration.AddProfile((Profile) Activator.CreateInstance(profile));
        }

    }

    private static IEnumerable<Type> GetLoadableTypes(Assembly assembly)
    {
        try
        {
            return assembly.GetTypes();
        }
        catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException e)
        {
            return e.Types.Where(t => t != null);
        }
    }
}
```

Thats the exception I get when I go to a certain route:

```
None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'AutoMapper.MappingEngine' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'AutoMapper.IConfigurationProvider configurationProvider' of constructor 'Void .ctor(AutoMapper.IConfigurationProvider)'.
Cannot resolve parameter 'AutoMapper.IConfigurationProvider configurationProvider' of constructor 'Void .ctor(AutoMapper.IConfigurationProvider, AutoMapper.Internal.IDictionary`2[AutoMapper.Impl.TypePair,AutoMapper.IObjectMapper], System.Func`2[System.Type,System.Object])'.
```

**QUESTION**

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Just as an aside, I don't recommend making IMappingEngine a dependency. Just use the real thing.

Comment: yes the Mapper seem to have the profiles loaded as I add the profiles to the Mapper.xxx but the imappingEngine has no profiles I get an exception... So you advise to use the Mapper.Map directly in the controller?

Comment: Yeah, I haven't personally seen a need to inject AutoMapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error come from this line :

```
builder.RegisterType<MappingEngine>().As<IMappingEngine>();
```

This line tell *Autofac* to instanciate a `MappingEngine` when you need a `IMappingEngine`. If you look at the available constructor of `MappingEngine` you will see that *Autofac* can't use any of them because it can't inject required parameters.

Here are the available constructor of `MappingEngine`

```
public MappingEngine(IConfigurationProvider configurationProvider)
public MappingEngine(IConfigurationProvider configurationProvider, 
                     IDictionary<TypePair, IObjectMapper> objectMapperCache, 
                     Func<Type, object> serviceCtor)
```

One of the solution to fix this issue is to tell *Autofac* how to create your `MappingEngine` you can do it by using a delegate registration.

```
builder.Register(c => new MappingEngine(...)).As<IMappingEngine>();
```

You can also register a `IConfigurationProvider` by doing so, *Autofac* will be able to automatically find the good constructor.

The easiest way to fix this issue is to register a `IConfigurationProvider` in *Autofac*

```
builder.Register(c => new ConfigurationStore(new TypeMapFactory(), MapperRegistry.Mappers))
       .As<IConfigurationProvider>()
       .SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<MappingEngine>()
       .As<IMappingEngine>();
```

You can also find further information here : [AutoMapper, Autofac, Web API, and Per-Request Dependency Lifetime Scopes](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2014/03/25/automapper-autofac-web-api-and-per-request-dependency-lifetime-scopes.aspx/)